# Install PHP and oci8 extension on centos 6.5

Tags: php, oracle11g, centos, oci8

I have installed PHP on Centos6.5 from help given [Install Php](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138019/php-5-5-13-on-centos-6-5-with-yum)
PHP version is 5.5.16

For installing the OCI8 Extension I executed the following

1. downloaded the RPMs and installed

   rpm -Uvh oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm

   rpm -Uvh oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm
2. executed the command `pecl install oci8`

   For this it gave error `bash: /usr/bin/pecl: No such file or directory`,  for this I executed `yum install php-pear`.
3. Executed the command `pecl install oci8`
   It is giving the following error

   downloading oci8-2.0.8.tgz ...

   Starting to download oci8-2.0.8.tgz (190,854 bytes)

   .........................................done: 190,854 bytes

   11 source files, building

   running: phpize

   Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php

   The php-devel package is required for use of this command.

   ERROR: `phpize' failed
4. To check if php-devel is installed i executed `rpm -qa | grep php`

The result :

```
php55w-opcache-5.5.16-1.w6.x86_64

php55w-common-5.5.16-1.w6.x86_64

php55w-process-5.5.16-1.w6.x86_64

php55w-cli-5.5.16-1.w6.x86_64

php55w-xml-5.5.16-1.w6.x86_64

php55w-5.5.16-1.w6.x86_64

php-pear-1.9.5-3.el6.remi.noarch
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To build pecl modules, phpize needs access to the source files that PHP was built from. You only have the PHP binaries installed, not the source code, so phpize can't proceed (your step 4 show that you have php & php-cli installed, but not php-devel).

You need to download & install an RPM (or perform a yum install) that provides the PHP source code for the version of PHP that you've got installed.

From the names of the installed packages that you've listed, my guess is you need to download & install an RPM named something like php55w-devel-5.5.16-1.w6.x86_6, or run yum install php55w-devel